# Group by first element of the array in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have a column "numbers" with array values. If I select the column in a query, the result looks like:

```
["40432","83248","1"]
["40432","8923","7723"]
["2340","837","20309"]
["290348","83248","20309","187"]
["98184897","98234","20309"]
["40432","83248"]
["2340"]
```

Now, I'd like to group the results on only the first value in the array and count them. The result should look like:

```
value    amount
40432    3
2340     2
290348   1
98184897 1
```

How do I arrange this? How should the query look like?

I tried things like:

```
SELECT.... WHERE split(TO_JSON_STRING(numbers), ',')[ordinal(1)] as firstNumber ......
```

But this did not result in the desired data.